# Can "advice-add ... :filter-args" detect if the advised function was called interactively?

Tags: interactive, advice, nadvice

Using `advice-add` from `nadvice.el`, I am trying to add a `:filter-args` advice to an interactive function. Is it somehow possible for it to detect, whether the advised function has been called interactively?

I was trying to use `called-interactively-p`, but `M-x describe-function called-interactively-p` says:

> This function is very brittle, it **may fail to return the intended
>   result** when the code is debugged, **advised**, or instrumented in some
>   form. [...]
>
> Instead of using this function, it is cleaner and more reliable to
>   give your function an **extra optional argument** whose ‘interactive’ spec
>   specifies non-nil unconditionally ("p" is a good way to do this), or
>   via `(not (or executing-kbd-macro noninteractive))`.

Sadly, neither works:

- The brittleness of `called-interactively-p` makes it useless here; Only around advise will detect interactiveness correctly with `called-interactively-p`, but then the original function doesn't see the interactive call that way anymore.
- The suggested workaround is actually wrong. `noninteractive` determines whether the emacs session is interactive, not whether the command was called interactively.

### Minimal working example for `called-interactively-p`

```
(defun tmpdemo-command (&rest args)
  (interactive '(was called interactively))
  (message "tmpdemo-command:     %-3S %-3S" 
    (called-interactively-p)
    (not (or executing-kbd-macro noninteractive)))
  (message "%S" args))

(advice-add #'tmpdemo-command :around #'tmpdemo-around)
(advice-add #'tmpdemo-command :filter-args #'tmpdemo-filter-args)

(defun tmpdemo-around (oldfun &rest args)
  (message "tmpdemo-around:      %-3S %-3S"
    (called-interactively-p)
    (not (or executing-kbd-macro noninteractive)))
  (apply oldfun args))

(defun tmpdemo-filter-args (args)
  (message "tmpdemo-filter-args: %-3S %-3S"
    (called-interactively-p)
    (not (or executing-kbd-macro noninteractive)))
  args)
```

When executing it interactively as `M-x tmpdemo-command`:

```
tmpdemo-filter-args: nil t      
tmpdemo-around:      t   t  <-- Only the around advise sees the
tmpdemo-command:     nil t      expected result.
(was called interactively)
```

When running it non-interactively as `(tmpdemo-command 'noninteractive)`

```
tmpdemo-filter-args: nil t  <-- the suggested workaround gives
tmpdemo-around:      nil t      the wrong result!!
tmpdemo-command:     nil t  
(noninteractive)
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the `noninteractive` suggestion, the idea is to do `(defun tmpdemo-command (interactive-call &rest args) (interactive (list (not (or executing-kbd-macro noninteractive)) 'etc)) ...)` and then check the `interactive-call` argument *instead* of using `called-interactive-p`. That suggestion is not applicable if you're trying advise a function that's already using `called-interactive-p` (i.e., not following the suggestion) though.

Comment: @npostavs - I am trying to advise `shell-command`, so mostly the problem is, that I can't just add an argument without breaking things.

Comment: "I can't just add an argument" - Right. But as far as I can tell `shell-command` doesn't use `called-interactively-p`, so it seems like you may have asked the wrong question.

Comment: @npostavs The main problem is that the advise has no reliable way to detect an interactive call, when the interface of the original function cannot be changed. I mostly just meant to show, that even *trying* to may cause further breakage, e.g. when a function has two `:around` advises -- only one of them will be able to detect interactive calls, and they may not know if each other (e.g. user configuration and a package-provided advise).

Answer (score 1):

As npostavs explains in a comment, the noninteractive suggestion is to do:

```
(defun foo (&optional interactivep)
  (interactive "p")
  ...
  ...use `interactivep' when you want to know if the call was interactive.
  ...)
```

which corresponds to `(called-interactive-p 'any)` or

```
(defun foo (&optional interactivep)
  (interactive (list (not (or executing-kbd-macro noninteractive))))
  ...
  ...use `interactivep' when you want to know if the call was interactive.
  ...)
```

which corresponds to `(called-interactive-p 'interactive)`, or even:

```
(defun foo (&optional interactivep)
  (interactive "p")
  ...
  ... use `(and interactivep
  ...           (not (or executing-kbd-macro noninteractive)))'
  ... when you want to know if the call was interactive.
  ...)
```

Note that you can also make the `:around` case work "correctly" (with the usual caveat that `called-interactively-p` remains brittle) as follows:

```
(defun tmpdemo-around (oldfun &rest args)
  (message "tmpdemo-around:      %-3S %-3S"
           (called-interactively-p)
           (not (or executing-kbd-macro noninteractive)))
  (apply (if (called-interactively-p 'any)
             #'funcall-interactively #'funcall)
         oldfun args))
```

Comment: I.e., it is *possible* to make `called-interactively-p` work correctly in an around advise in such a manner that for the function nothing changes. But that still leaves the advise vulnerable to an incorrect result from `called-interactively-p` caused by an additional `:around` advise, correct?

Comment: @kdb: That's right.  The inherent brittleness can still bite you ;-)

Comment: There is also the issue that around advice is pretty awful for debugging - try using `trace-function` with it :/